# Clarification of one sided vs two sided p value following permutation testing

Tags: r, correlation, p-value, permutation

I am unsure as to how to compute a two sided p value following permutation testing, following different examples online.

For example, this post [Two-sided permutation test vs. two one-sided](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34052/two-sided-permutation-test-vs-two-one-sided), gets the proportion of the absolute correlation coefficients from the permutation test greater than or equal to the absolute non-permuted correlation coefficient.

When I ran this, here were my results;

```
     set.seed(1)
     x <- runif(20)
     y <- 0.5 * x
     y <- y + rnorm(20)

     #set up for the permutation, compute observed R
     nullR <- numeric(length = 1000)
     nullR[1] <- cor(x, y) ## obsered R in [1]
     N <- length(x)

    #permutation test
    for(i in seq_len(999) + 1) {
         nullR[i] <- cor(x[sample(N)], y)
     }

   >one side H1 R > 0
   >sum(nullR >= nullR[1]) / length(nullR)
   [1] 0.929
   >one side H1 R < 0
   > sum(nullR <= nullR[1]) / length(nullR)
   [1] 0.072
   > two sided
   > sum(abs(nullR) >= abs(nullR[1])) / length(nullR)
  [1] 0.155
```

Whilst, this website (https://dgarcia-eu.github.io/SocialDataScience/5_SocialNetworkPhenomena/056_PermutationTests/PermutationTests) calculates a two sided p value following permutations of correlations as:

```
         p_value_Cor <- (sum(nullR>=nullR[1])+1)/length(nullR)
```

which gets the same value as the first one sided test 0.93.

Q1) which is the right way to calculate a two sided p value following permutation of correlations?

Q2) if I used cor.test, which would get the test statistic and estimate, which should I use to calculate the p value and why, the estimate like they have done above or the test statistic? In my own data, I would be using Spearman correlation.

Any clarity would be appreciated.

Comment: The `+ 1` is common. It ensures that your p-value will never be an exact 0, regardless of how many (or, more importantly, few) permutations you perform.

Comment: @Roland thank you for your comment - was wondering whether you would choose the test statistic or the estimate (like in the example above) to calculate the p value?