# Bootstrapping vs permutations for correlation hypothesis testing

Tags: r, correlation, bootstrap, permutation-test

I would like to test the null hypothesis that there is no difference between the outcomes of the Spearmann correlation test run on pairs of data (x,y) from the original dataset I have , vs one where the y value may have been permuted or pairs of data  (xi, yi) has been sampled with replacement (bootstrapping).

I have come across examples of calculating p values from permutating

[Two-sided permutation test vs. two one-sided](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34052/two-sided-permutation-test-vs-two-one-sided)

- https://davidzeleny.net/wiki/doku.php/recol:monte-carlo-pearson

And then also bootstrapping p values
[Computing p-value using bootstrap with R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20701/computing-p-value-using-bootstrap-with-r/)

and [Get p-value of coefficients in regression models using bootstrap](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/272417/get-p-value-of-coefficients-in-regression-models-using-bootstrap) (for regression not correlation).

Presume I need to calculate a two-sided p value - but permutation using the correlation coefficient and bootstrapping examples above use the test statistic. Not sure which (if any ) is the most statistically valid way to test the null hypothesis above.

Any advice or pointers appreciated.

Comment: See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20217/bootstrap-vs-permutation-hypothesis-testing) for more background; if a hypothesis test is of primary interest then permutation is the way to go.